# CKeditor changes character "š" to "&scaron;" in source

Tags: ckeditor

For my site I am using CKeditor to add/edit content and I noticed when I write character š in source code it is changed to `&scaron;` - this causes problems when I do search in the database, so I am wondering how to fix this, so that that character will stay written in the source code the same way (not changed)?

I can fix this by adding this to config:

```
config.entities = false;
```

But with this, everything is disabled (even quotes, double quotes,... are now not changed in source), so this is not the best solution, right?

I also tried with those settings, but they don't help:

```
config.IncludeGreekEntities = false;
config.IncludeLatinEntities = false;
```

What else can I try? Is there any way to manually set that some characters should not be converted?

Comment: What is the reason you would like to selectively encode characters? Only some are used for search in the database? As this is the issue strictly connected to the output, maybe some conversion outside CKEditor (after fetching content) could be used?

Comment: The problem is with character "š" - in database it's stored as &scaron; and search doesn't work on site (no result is shown with any word containing "š".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command seems to work, I no longer have problems with `&scaron;` (other special chars are still converted - like quote, which is fine):

```
CKEDITOR.config.entities_latin = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

If it causes an issue with your search implementation, it is not only a "š" character which will be an issue here but all special characters which may be used for search. I don't think CKEditor has a config to whitelist entities which should not be encoded.

I would suggest just decoding this characters after getting data from CKEditor, like:

```
var map = { '&scaron;': 'š', '&agrave;': 'à' };
editor.getData().replace( /&scaron;|&agrave;/g, function( m ) { return map[ m ] } );
```

**----- EDIT:**

To integrate it with CKEditor one may use [toDataFormat](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-toDataFormat) event:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' ),
    map = { '&scaron;': 'š', '&agrave;': 'à' };

editor.on( 'toDataFormat', function( evt ) {
    evt.data.dataValue = evt.data.dataValue.replace( /&scaron;|&agrave;/g, function( m ) { return map[ m ] } );
}, null, null, 16 );
```

See [working example on codepen](https://codepen.io/f1ames/pen/JrMWQV?editors=1010).

Comment: Where should I put this code to? I tried in config.js and to JS which loads CKeditor, but in both cases it didn't work.

Comment: @SilverSilencer I have updated my answer showing how to integrate it with CKEditor.

Comment: For some reason my CK editor ignores toDataFormat - maybe something else is causing some error I will check and hopefully get it to work since it works on codepen. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Only had deleted "scaron" and "Scaron" from ckeditor.js source.

Comment: Where should looking for   "scaron"  ?

Comment: It is not clear what this post is supposed to contribute. It does not look like an answer and anything else is not appropriate as an answer. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead If this is an supposed to be an answer you need to [edit9 it to make the helpfully answering part of this more obvious. Frankly I get an impression that you basically say "Me too, solved now, thanks.".